# Team Foundation Server 2017 - Database Restore failing

Tags: tfs

I am running through my disaster recovery process for TFS 2017/18 and am trying to restore the databases to the SQL server 2016 instance on the same machine as the TFS Admin tool.

I am using the TFS Administration Tool to take the full backups and also to restore them.

The issue is that after the ReportServer and ReportServerTmp DBs get restored, the TFS_Warehouse and other TFS_ databases hang while doing the restore.

The log file shows the error message:  *Login Failed for user 'domain\machinename$' Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'ReportServer'. [CLIENT: ]*

The SQL Server has the NT Authority/Network Service account and I have also tried giving it 'domain\machinename$' as well.

I have compared it to another Virtual Machine that has a standard installation of SQL Server and TFS Server on it and I cannot see any obvious difference.

Does anyone know of a solution for this?
Regards

Comment: Update:  If I use SSMS and manually restore each database it works. However, I understand the recomended process is to use the TFS Admin tool to do the restore.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message "`Login Failed for user 'domain\machinename$' Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'ReportServer'. [CLIENT: ]`".

Seems the related database had been dropped (database missed) or there is any service is trying to access the database which does not exist.
**That means you did not restore the databases correctly or you did not really full back up the databases correctly**. And when you use SSMS and manually restore each database, the related database online again, so it works.

Yes we recommend use the **Scheduled Backups** feature wizard to backup or restore the DBs.  However you need to note below things:

> You can use the backups you made of the original deployment to restore
>   the data from that deployment to the new server. **When restoring the
>   data, be sure to restore all databases and the SharePoint Farm to the
>   same point in time.** If you followed the guidance in [Create a backup
>   schedule and plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/config-backup-sched-plan), you used the **Scheduled Backups** feature to
>   create your backups. You will use these backups to restore your data.
>
> If you manually configured your backups, you cannot use the Restore
>   wizard in Scheduled Backups to restore those databases. You must
>   manually restore them using the software you used to back them up.
>
> ***Source : [Restore the databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/tut-single-svr-restore-dbs)***

Generally, we can use the SQL Server Profiler to trace the error, then debug accordingly. Within SQL Server Management Studio , choose Tools menu and then SQL Profiler with Audit Login/Logout, User Error Message events selected and check the relative entries of login fails. See below threads for details:

- [SQL Server Error 18456: Finding the Missing Databases](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2581/sql-server-error-18456-finding-the-missing-databases/)
- [Login failed for user 'domain\username'. Reason: Failed to open the
  explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: ]](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/8453abf1-2f9a-48be-805f-4839396b028a/login-failed-for-user-domainusername-reason-failed-to-open-the-explicitly-specified-database?forum=sqlsecurity)

---

**UPDATE:**

For the account issue, please refer to the **Required permissions** part in this article :[Restore the databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfs-server/admin/backup/tut-single-svr-restore-dbs). Just add the TFS **service account** as the **sysadmin** role, then try it again.

> **Required permissions**
>
> To perform these procedures, you must be a member of the following
>   groups or have the following permissions:
>
> - A member of the **Administrators** security group on the server.
> - Either a member of the **SQL Server System Administrator** security    group, or your **SQL Server Perform Back Up and Create Maintenance
>
>     Plan** permission must be set to **Allow**.
> - A member of the **sysadmin** security group for the databases for    Team Foundation.
> - A member of the **Farm Administrators** group.

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks,  there are no missing databases, the backup was done within TFS Admin tool.  It will not restore those backups due to an incorrect account. I am trying to work out what the account should be :)

Comment: Hi - if I restore the databases using SQL restore they all restore correctly, it is only when I use the tfs tool to restore that they dont. The tool is connecting to SQL server using an account that does not exist.  It has nothing to do with the quality of the backup.  The SQL log says account not found - not invalid backup :)

Comment: @AndyW Yes, it's the account issue, you need to add your **service account** to the corresponding groups mentioned in the updated answer.

Comment: The issue is not resolved.   For testing I am manually restoring each database however, I am concious that this may intoroduce issues with transactions across multiple databases.  My serice account is set up correctly.  However, it is worth noting that when the databases are being restored, no Application Tier exists at this stage.  The TFS backup/Restore process is separate from this - I do not know what account it uses (other than a local one).  I believe this may be a known TFS bug

Comment: @AndyW It should be the permission issue with the service account, I suggest you check that again.

Comment: I have - it isnt - unfortunately, there isnt a way to log a bug with TFS